# How can I set up a "public" or a "team" folder in Google Drive (G suite)?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

I'd like to have 2 types of folders:

- A `Public` Folder, everyone in the company can see in their "Shared with me" section and edit
- Few `Team-specific` folders, everyone in the team can see and edit (a
  team is an emails' group, I can set them up in the Admin console)

The folders should be seen by default by anyone from the designated groups, ie no special assignment in shared settings of the folder should occur. How can I do it please?

Answer (score 1):

Following my talk with the Google G Suite support representative, the answer is that [Team Drives](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started-team-drive/) are exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately, Team Drives are not available in the Basic version. I'd wish Google would help more regarding building for scale.